# How to display score as an HTML tag that can be updated from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, buttonclick

so I am working on a quiz app and need a way to display score on the screen that can be updated from onclick events on wrong/correct answers. Since I am new to programming and really bad at HTML, how do I do this? Here's a code snippet for some context:

```
<h1 style = "position:relative;left:10px;color:#DDDDDD"> SCORE: <span id = "score"> 0 </span>  </h1> //the score h1 tag with the actual score

document.getElementById("r1").addEventListener("click", function(){
  score.innerHTML += 10 //supposed to increase score but isn't working as intended
  r1.remove() //remove the buttons with the answers to free space for the next questions
  r2.remove()
  r3.remove()
  q.remove()


 }) //an onclick event listener on a button with the right answer to a question
```

Comment: use any element you want. Most programmers would use a `<span></span>` and update it with JS: `innerHTML`

Comment: Atleast please show what you have tried yet?

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to modify the score from Javascript. The only problem that remains is that for each question answered correctly the score would need to go up by 10, and for each question answered incorrectly it would need to go down by 10. I am not entirely sure on how to do this so I just tried to do 'score.innerHTML += 10', and 'score.innerHTML -= 10'. Obviously, the problem here is that the score doesn't actually get bigger as expected but "10" just gets added to the span innerHTML, and for wrong answers it just gives NaN. How do I fix this? Thanks for the help

Comment: then post the code you trying to sue if you want actual help. Otherwise we just guessing in the blue

Comment: you can find the code at https://codepen.io/emaminek/pen/ZEBdpGw

Comment: insert the code directly into your question (edit your question) and poste it as a stcksnippet (ctrl + m). code must always eb included directly in the question itself.

Comment: ok, I modified the question with  a code snippet that should hopefully be insightful enough to you. Sorry for the inconvenience. It includes extracts from the html and JS code relevant to the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the score, load the score from the element by using `parseInt(document.querySelector('.class').innerHTML)` so that you get it as `integer`. You need an integer string to actually be able to calculate with it. Otherwise you get a `NaN` (not a number) error. Then use `.innerHTML = element + 10;` or `.innerHTML = element - 10;`

```js
function correct() {
  let score = parseInt(document.querySelector('.score').innerHTML);
  document.querySelector('.score').innerHTML = score + 10;
}

function incorrect() {
  let score = parseInt(document.querySelector('.score').innerHTML);
  document.querySelector('.score').innerHTML = score - 10;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="correct()">Correct Anwser</button>
<button onclick="incorrect()">False Anwser</button>

<p>Score: <span class="score">0</span></p>
```